# Representing items in a set of sets, editable in real time, as a web based tool

Tags: open-source, javascript, html, json

First question here, so bear with me if I get this whole thing a little wrong. Also preemptive thank you for your help.

I need a tool for displaying some data (let's pretend dog breeds).
Each breed appears a certain amount of times, but all dogs in the same breed are formally equal to each other. Those numbers are given during setup and are not mutable. I am, however, allowed to create or destroy as many kennels as I want.

I want to group all dogs into kennels. I also need to be able to validate groupings, because I don't want German Shepherds with Beagles, Shiba in greater numbers than 8, kennels with more than 15 dogs and so on (examples are made up).

I need to have the user be able to change the grouping on the fly. Ideally, drag and drop dogs into kennels.

Lastly, all of this needs to run on a web browser. I also need to import/export a given grouping on request. JSON is preferred as a data format but I'll take anything that can be converted from such format.

Now, I'm not afraid to deal with a complicated system as I'm definitely not new to programming, but I'd rather not build something from scratch as a web based application.

I do, however, need it open source.

I think I was clear enough, but language barrier might be a thing here so if I wasn't clear just ask again.